# Twilio call getting disconnected

Tags: node.js, lambda, twilio

I have created two Lambda functions.

Lambda function first:

```
module.exports.submit = (event, context, callback) => {

 const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  /** using Twiml Gather record the message and generate callback */
   const gather = twiml.gather({
    input:'speech',
    finishOnKey:'',
    action:'url of second lambda function' 

  });
  twiml.say('We did not recived any inputs, Thanks for calling')

  callback(null, response.success(twiml.toString()));

};
```

Lambda function second

```
module.exports.submit = (event, context, callback) => {

  const twiml = new textReponse();
  console.log(querystring.parse(event.body));

  twiml.say(`Hello,kshitiz how may i help you`);

  callback(null, response.success(twiml.toString()));

};
```

The problem I am facing is of call disconnection. So when user call on my Twilio number, I am able to use `twiml -<gather>-<speech>` and call second Lambda function, and second Lambda function is able to receive the "speechresult". When Lambda second return the result, I am able to listen that in mobile, but the call gets disconnected soon after that. I want my call to continue and to be disconnected only when user disconnect it. 
I have tried different solutions but could not make it work, seems i am missing something.

Comment: What do you expect `Twilio` to do. After you got your message across. I guess that is intended behaviour. %)P

Comment: I want to use Twilio as a normal phone call behaviour, something like voice chat bot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with some more understanding of Twiml. I have fixed the problem. The solution is to use  [Twilio redirect features](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/redirect)

Hope it helps other